# QGIS - line between ordered layer of points - take attributes of both points

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion

I have a series of locations in time in a point layer. I want to make a line layer of lines between consecutive points that takes the attributes (in my case, a timestamp) of the 1 points it connects. 
Is there an existing plugin or script that does this? The plugins I found makes it a long line.

A solution I thought of was to use PointtoPaths plugin, then explode the resulting line, and use a spatial join to somehow get the attributes of the points.

Comment: How do you want to "take the attributes of the points"? Aggregate them? Add a "measure" dimension to each line vertex?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. I would like the line between the two points to have the timestamp of that point (which is in the attribute table belowing to the point layer).